# jQuery Add Image Title Attribute from Alt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, attributes

```
jQuery('img').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('title', jQuery(this).attr('alt'));
})
```

How can I modify the code above so that it only applies the title attribute from alt if it doesn't already have a title attribute? In other words, if the image already has a non-empty title attribute, this code shouldn't execute.

Comment: Use this Selector: `jQuery('img:not([title!=""][title])').each(function() { jQuery(this).attr('title', jQuery(this).attr('alt')); })`

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery('img').each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.attr('title') && $this.attr('alt')) {
        $this.attr('title', $this.attr('alt'));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('img:not([title!=""][title])').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('title', jQuery(this).attr('alt'));
})
```

You can use this selector which will take care of all `img` tags with or without `title` attribute exists and if exists, it should be `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

By using a condition to check if the 'alt' attribute exists:

```
if (jQuery(this).attr('alt') != undefined) {
    jQuery(this).attr('title', jQuery(this).attr('alt'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
jQuery('img').each(function() {
    var jq=jquery(this)
    var title= jq.attr('title');
     if(title == undefined)
       jq.attr('title', jq.attr('alt'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the setter version of .attr() like

```
jQuery('img').attr('title', function () {
    if (!this.title) {
        return this.alt
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zdLgwbop/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
jQuery('img').each(function () {
    var $el = jQuery(this),
        title = $el.attr('title'),
        alt = $el.attr('alt');
    if (title === undefined || title == '' || alt === undefined || alt == '')
        return;

    $el.attr('title', alt);
});
```

The code above will skip all images that have an empty or undefined title or alt attribute.

Answer (score 0):

$('img').attr('alt','image here');
$('img').attr('title','company name')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).